# css only-of-type and other selectors not working

Tags: css, css-selectors

when using `only-of-type` or `only-child` in this scenario, it is not working.

The 2nd block which has only 1 child of `.stx` should have a background, but it is not working. can anyone tell me what am i doing wrong?

https://jsfiddle.net/h90fmmwd/1/

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 15px;
}
.column {
  display: flex flex-direction: column;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.spacer:before {
  content: '- - -';
}
.stx {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.stx:only-of-type {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">

  <div class="column">
    <div class="row">
      <ul class="column">
        <li class="spacer"></li>
        <li class="stx">
          <div class="content">
            <div class="block">content 1</div>
            <div class="block">content 2</div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="stx">
          <div class="content">
            <div class="block">content 1</div>
            <div class="block">content 2</div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="spacer"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="column">
    <div class="row">
      <ul class="column">
        <li class="spacer"></li>
        <li class="stx ">
          <div class="content">
            <div class="block">content 1</div>
            <div class="block">content 2</div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="spacer"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <div class="row">
      <ul class="column">
        <li class="spacer"></li>
        <li class="stx ">
          <div class="content">
            <div class="block">content 1</div>
            <div class="block">content 2</div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="stx ">
          <div class="content">
            <div class="block">content 1</div>
            <div class="block">content 2</div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="stx ">
          <div class="content">
            <div class="block">content 1</div>
            <div class="block">content 2</div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="spacer"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> [`only-of-type`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#only-of-type-pseudo) - Represents an **element** that has a parent element and whose parent element has no other element children with the same expanded element name. Same as `:first-of-type:last-of-type` or `:nth-of-type(1):nth-last-of-type(1)`, but with a lower specificity.

In you example you have 3 `li` items, and only one has `.stx` class, so if you remove the first and last `li`(in your example that's the `li.spacer` elements) only one `li` element would be left and the then the selector would apply:

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 15px;
}
.column {
  display: flex flex-direction: column;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.spacer:before {
  content: '- - -';
}
.stx {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.stx:only-of-type {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="column">
  <!--<li class="spacer"></li>-->
  <li class="stx ">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="block">content 1</div>
      <div class="block">content 2</div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <!--<li class="spacer"></li>-->
</ul>

<hr>

<ul class="column">
  <li class="spacer"></li>
  <li class="stx ">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="block">content 1</div>
      <div class="block">content 2</div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="spacer"></li>
</ul>
```

So the `only-of-type` works as expected in your OP.

Answer (score 0):

`only-of-type` matches any element who is the only child from it's direct parent, `.stx` it's not an only child from `column` container, so it will do nothing.

If you applied that on `.content` then, it will select each element which has `.content` class because they are the only child from `.stx` container `.stx .content:only-of-type { background: red; }`.

So, to apply that on `.block` put only one element in container ( put one `.block` in any tag such `span` );

> you could achieve the same selection as `:only-of-type` with
>   `:first-of-type` `:last-of-type` or `:nth-of-type(1):` `nth-last-of-type(1)`. [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/o/only-of-type/)

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 15px;
}
.column {
  display: flex
    flex-direction: column;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.spacer:before {
  content:'- - -';
}

.stx {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.stx .content div:only-of-type { background: red; }
```

```html
<div class="row">

  <div class="column">
    <div class="row">
      <ul class="column">
        <li class="spacer"></li>
        <li class="stx">
          <div class="content">
            <span><div class="block">content 1</div></span>
            <div class="block">content 2</div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="stx">
          <div class="content">
            <div class="block">content 1</div>
            <div class="block">content 2</div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="spacer"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="column">
    <div class="row">
      <ul class="column">
        <li class="spacer"></li>
        <li class="stx ">
          <div class="content">
            <div class="block">content 1</div>
            <div class="block">content 2</div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="spacer"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <div class="row">
      <ul class="column">
        <li class="spacer"></li>
        <li class="stx ">
          <div class="content">
            <div class="block">content 1</div>
            <div class="block">content 2</div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="stx ">
          <div class="content">
            <div class="block">content 1</div>
            <div class="block">content 2</div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="stx ">
          <div class="content">
            <div class="block">content 1</div>
            <div class="block">content 2</div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="spacer"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Only of Type works only when that element is not repeated in its parent scope

In your dom apply .stx class to content div i.e., `<div class="content stx"></div>`